# Excel VBA keep Listbox from workbook persistent after sourse is closed

Tags: vba, userform

I have a listbox on a userform that I am populating from an external workbook. If I keep the source spreadsheet open the listbox dispays correctly. When I close the external workbook the listbox seems no longer displays correctly and if you scroll the listbox text is replaced with a bunch of non print characters.

I launch the user form and when the user selects a checkbox the userform is expended to show the additional fields.

```
Private Sub chkRepaceFromList_Click()
    Dim sFileLocation As String
    'When checkbox is checked, add replace from list option
    If chkRepaceFromList = True Then
      Me.Width = 400
      sFileLocation = "C:\My File.xlsx"
      'Populate listbox with items in replace from list spreadsheet
      Call UpdateReplaceList
    Else
      Me.Width = 160
    End If
End Sub
```

UpdateReplaceList Populates the listbox with items from "C:\My File.xlsx"

```
Sub UpdateReplaceList()
    Dim sFileLocation As String
    Dim wbList As Workbook
    sFileLocation = "C:\My File.xlsx"
    Set wbList = Workbooks.Open(sFileLocation)
    wbList.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Select
    Range("A10", Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Select ' Select all data
    With lstReplaceListListBox
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "100;100"
        '.RowSource = wbList.Range("A1:C20").Address
        .RowSource = Selection.Address
        '.RowSource = vList
    End With
    wbList.Close
End Sub
```

I would prefer not to keep "C:\My File.xlsx" open any longer than needed and if I do not close it the chkRepaceFromList_Click() event gets triggered and It tries to open the file that is already open.

I am using the Sub UpdateReplaceList as I need to use the same code when some other buttons are pressed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn's out that if you declare an unallocated array.

```
Dim vList() As Variant
```

It becomes allocated when data is assigned

```
vList = Selection 'copy data from workbook to memory as an array
```

Then you can assign the array to the listbox.

```
With lstReplaceListListBox
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "100;100"
        .list = vList 'Copy array to listbox
    End With
```

And this stays persistent in the listbox when the source workbook is closed.